# Catching React Native error in Obj C

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, exception, react-native

I am looking to prevent any unexpected raised Exceptions in my React Native app from crashing the entire app.

Is there any way to handle exceptions raised in the React Native JS on the obj c side.
 Since the process extends beyond the App Delegate, a simple `@try/@catch` simply doesn't cut it.

I already have implemented `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` which I have set up to provide a failure stack trace, but it falls short in terms of gracefully handling RN Issues

Comment: You should be fixing your app so that exceptions don't get thrown, not trying to catch them

Comment: @dan  we are working very hard to ensure that the app doesn't break, but that doesn't mean that we are able to for see every potential bug that can occur. When any downtime contributes to a serious loss of business, it is best to be as defensive as possible

Comment: ObjC exceptions are (almost always) thrown for programming errors that can't be recovered from.  There is no way for you to catch an arbitrary exception and have your app recover from it and continue running.

Comment: I am not necessarily looking for a way to handle arbitrary exception, I am looking for a strategy that would help with the errors raised through React Native.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to research a lot because it's very poorly documented. In the end, a friend of mine helped me out with this problem.

You need to set

```
//This will tell react native that you are taking responsibility of fatal crashes.
RCTSetFatalHandler(^(NSError *error) {});
```

Also, create an RCTExceptionsManager instance and pass it in the extraModulesForBridge method of your class abiding by RCTBridgeDelegate protocol.

```
- (NSArray *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
    return @[[RCTExceptionsManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
}
```

The two methods that you need to implement are:

```
 - (void)handleSoftJSExceptionWithMessage:(NSString *)message stack:(NSArray *)stack exceptionId:(NSNumber *)exceptionId;
 - (void)handleFatalJSExceptionWithMessage:(NSString *)message stack:(NSArray *)stack exceptionId:(NSNumber *)exceptionId;
```

This gives you full control of the fatal exception handling and react native crashes won't crash the app.

Comment: I know only react native. can you explain more about your answer like which file I have to add this line `RCTSetFatalHandler(^(NSError *error) {});` ? like wise all methods you have given above where I have to add these lines. where and how to implement `handleSoftJSExceptionWithMessage`. please explain and edit your answer more detail, then I can understand